# Converting complex hashmap to JSON using jackson jersey

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey-2.0

Hi I am using jackson for converting to json for my api project. the dependency i have used is

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have two classes

TimeInterval and Cost

I need to create a map

```
Map<TimeInterval, Cost>
```

which will be converted to JSON using the jackson provider.

It converts it fine but the key i get is the toString as a string not as json object.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks
Sanjeev

Comment: So properties of TimeInterval are keys and Cost are values in resultant Hashmap

Comment: Having some complex object as a map key is a bad practice.

Comment: One note: your JAX-RS provider version should match Jackson version: 2.4 and 1.9 are NOT compatible. So perhaps upgrade Jackson; group id for 2.x would `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` and artifact `jackson-databind`

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate?
JSON is essentially a key,value pair both being string or value being array, docuemnt but that again will be in string at leaf level.

Comment: More specifically JSON keys are ALWAYS Strings, and can not be anything else; whereas value can be any valid JSON value type, including Object, Array, String, Number, Boolean or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay convert both classes into HashMap like

```
Map<String,Object> map_values = mapper.convertValue(Object(TimeInterval/Cost), Map.class);
```

And built third hashmap according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a simple textual presentation of data, the following page actually define the JSON syntax in one short HTML page http://json.org/.

As you can see the basics building blocks are object and arrays and some data types (string number Boolean and null).

If you need a hash map, you can take the fact that basic object members are somewhat of dictionary where the key have to be a string and the value is and object (or an array in case the same time interval has few costs).

So now you need to provide your own business logic to provide a unique string representation for your TimeInterval that can be parse back to object on the code that consume the json.

Let’s say for example the time value of start and end of TimeInterval separated by "-"

e,g.  Your time TimeInterval  toString will look like

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    //start and end are of type Date
    return start.getTime()+"-"+end.getTime();
}
```

Now the resulting json will look like

```
{
    "1420667419892-1420698059892" : {
        "ammount" : 10.9,
        "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "1420698059892-1420706699892" : {
        "ammount" : 10.9,
        "currency" : "ERO"
    }
}
```

But if TimeInterval is more complicate and the option above is not possible.  You will need some surrogate key for TimeInterval, Then you will have to create Wrapping Object that will include  you dictionary and a set or existing  IntervalIdToCost

```
public class TimeToCostMapWarpper {
   //Map TimeInterval.Id to Cost
    Map<String, Cost> intervalIdToCost = new HashMap<>();
    Set<TimeInterval> timeIntervals = new HashSet<>();
 //getter/setter...
}
```

Now you will serialize the wrapper object and will get something like:

```
{
    "intervalIdToCost" : {
        "1f3fe6cf-7afe-4575-b8b2-bbe2067a99bd" : {
            "ammount" : 10.9,
            "currency" : "ERO"
        },
        "d2c880ce-ef41-48f8-8f4a-0ff73449e1c3" : {
            "ammount" : 10.9,
            "currency" : "USD"
        }
    },
    "timeIntervals" : [{
            "id" : "1f3fe6cf-7afe-4575-b8b2-bbe2067a99bd",
            "start" : 1420702028475,
            "end" : 1420710668475
        }, {
            "id" : "d2c880ce-ef41-48f8-8f4a-0ff73449e1c3",
            "start" : 1420693388475,
            "end" : 1420702028475
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess that you could think of other whys to implement this, just need to keep in mind that the output should contain enough data to parse the result easily in the consuming side.

Comment: Note that your first object above is invalid, since it has two identical keys.  Also, it's unwise to have a JSON object where the keys are "variables".  Far better to have an array of objects where the "variable" quantity is the value part of a key/value pair in each object.  (This is essentially what you did with the "timeIntervals" structure in the second example.)

Comment: I agree, but I guess it depends on your needs and preferences,